# Entity Framework seems to have invented a column that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here I am checking the database to get a list of spells where the id matches what's sent in by the user:

```
Spell spell = db.Spells.Where(x=>x.Id == spellId).FirstOrDefault();
```

The spell class looks like this:

```
public partial class Spell
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Page { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Range { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Components { get; set; }

    public bool? Ritual { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Duration { get; set; }

    public bool? Concentration { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CastingTime { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string School { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Classes { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Archetype { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Domains { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Oaths { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Circles { get; set; }
}
```

However, when that line executes, I get an error that `spellbook_id` is not a column.

I checked the query that's executing, and this is it:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Page] AS [Page], 
[Extent1].[Range] AS [Range], 
[Extent1].[Components] AS [Components], 
[Extent1].[Ritual] AS [Ritual], 
[Extent1].[Duration] AS [Duration], 
[Extent1].[Concentration] AS [Concentration], 
[Extent1].[CastingTime] AS [CastingTime], 
[Extent1].[Level] AS [Level], 
[Extent1].[School] AS [School], 
[Extent1].[Classes] AS [Classes], 
[Extent1].[Archetype] AS [Archetype], 
[Extent1].[Domains] AS [Domains], 
[Extent1].[Oaths] AS [Oaths], 
[Extent1].[Circles] AS [Circles], 
[Extent1].[Spellbook_Id] AS [Spellbook_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Spells] AS [Extent1]
```

As you can see, somehow EF is requesting a `Spellbook_Id` from the table, but it doesn't exist.  I'm not sure where it's getting that idea.  I do have a `Spellbook` class, which just has an id, a userid, and a `List<Spell>`, but the query I'm trying to run shouldn't be referencing Spellbook at all, and there are no foreign key constraints on dbo.Spells

EDIT: Added some more code per request

```
public class Spellbook
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Spell> Spells { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my context:

```
public partial class SpellbookAPIContext : DbContext
{
    public SpellbookAPIContext() : base("name=SpellbookAPIContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Spell> Spells { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Spellbook> Spellbooks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Description)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Page)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Range)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Components)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Duration)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.CastingTime)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.School)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Classes)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Archetype)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Domains)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Oaths)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spell>()
            .Property(e => e.Circles)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spellbook>()
            .Property(e => e.Id)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spellbook>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Spellbook>()
            .Property(e => e.UserId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a mapping class? Also, is the List you referred to on the Spellbook class a List of Spells?

Comment: It is, I typed that but I think it disappeared because I didn't use the backtick.  Let me update that.  And I am not using a mapping class yet because I haven't needed it

Comment: since Spellbook has a navigation property of type ICollection<Spell>, Spell needs a foreign key to the Spellbook table to tell which spells belong to which Spellbook. Since EF didnt find the FK, but it is required to establish the relationship, it invented it.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro but I developed it totally code-first, so wouldn't it have automatically created the FK?

Comment: obviously it is targeting a database with a differing schema. you should try to migrate the schema then, or use another initializer.

Answer (score 0):

> I do have a Spellbook class, which just has an id, a userid, and a List...

Would that be a list of Spells, perhaps? Maybe Entity Framework is assuming that you have a foreign key in Spell because Spellbook has a `ICollection<Spell>` property.

You might try posting your Spellbook code, as well as your Entity Framework configuration class. Entity Framework can be configured in three ways:

- Data Annotations on your models (see [Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583))
- Fluent configuration in your Entity Framework configuration class (see [Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620))
- Automatically by convention (see [Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx))

It could be that you have a relationship in one of those three areas.

Read more on [Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I added the Spellbook class as well as my whole context class.  I'm pretty new to EntityFramework.  In fact, this is the first time i've ever had more than one table.  This whole project is a huge learning experience for me